# XYZ dimensional array

Tags: javascript

Why is this code shown array[7][0] is undefined when it should have a value?

```
var tnotes = [];
var index = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    tnotes[i] = [];
}

var tx = 'B4';
var notes=['B5','A5','G5','F5','E5','D5','C5','B4','A4','G4','F4','E4','D4','C4']
var getNotes = notes.indexOf(tx);

if (getNotes != -1) {
    tnotes[getNotes][index][] = new Array(20)
    tnotes[getNotes][index][0] = tx //B4
    tnotes[getNotes][index][2] = '3sec'
    index++
}
console.log(tnotes[7][0])
```

Comment: Try printing `getNotes`

Comment: Please copy/paste your exact code. You've edited several times, removing and introducing syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a syntax error in defining one of your sub-arrays. The following line is incorrect:

```
    tnotes[getNotes][index][] = new Array(20)
```

You are introducing a third-dimension of your `tnotes` array without it being defined

It should be:

```
 tnotes[getNotes][index] = [];
```

Or if you really need the size parameter:

```
 tnotes[getNotes][index] = new Array(20);
```

After this, `tnotes[7][0]` should no longer be `undefined`. Also, please do yourself a favor and make sure you use semi-colons consistently, it's good practice and can save you many-a-headache.

Corrected code:

```js
var tnotes = [];
var index = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    tnotes[i] = [];
}

var tx = 'B4';
var notes = ['B5','A5','G5','F5','E5','D5','C5','B4','A4','G4','F4','E4','D4','C4'];
var getNotes = notes.indexOf(tx);

if (getNotes != -1) {
    tnotes[getNotes][index] = [];
    tnotes[getNotes][index][0] = tx; //B4
    tnotes[getNotes][index][2] = '3sec';
    index++;
}

console.log(tnotes[7][0]);
```

Comment: Nope, I have the correct array, was still editing my question. Perhaps you could delete and answer it again.

Comment: @MatthewDavis: I will edit. Your only error then is that you aren't defining `notes` array correctly.